# how to send sensor data from arduino yun thru http to interface with web api

Tags: mysql, curl, asp.net-web-api, arduino, webserver

Currently I am working on a self-interest project using Arduino Yun.

Basically is a object detection by using photodiode as a sensor to detect present/absent of an object in a specific location.
I wish to update on "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:80xx/api/UpdateObject/1" where 1
indicate present of an object and 0 indicate no object.

I am **stuck on updating the url from my arduino yun**.

Please help me on how can I update the url whenever there is object present/absent of an object.

your help is highly appreciated.
Thank you!!!

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

have you read the [Http client Yun official tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HttpClient) ?